# Getting the Android GpsLocationProvider object

Tags: android, locationmanager

I want to get to the class `GpsLocationProvider` on Android. I want to call a few methods of this class, like `setMinTime()`. 
Here is my code:

```
LocationManager lm = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
GpsLocationProvider pr = (GpsLocationProvider)lm.getProvider(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
```

And the problem is `GpsLocationProvider  class is unresolved`. I know that it is located in `com.android.internal.location.GpsLocationProvider` , but such import is unresolved as well, and `import com.android.internal.*;` doesn't help to resolve ``GpsLocationProvider` too. 
What does this mean? 
Thank you for any tips.

EDIT: I know that I can change most of the `LocationProvider` pararmeters through `LocationManager` like `LocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(String provider, long minTime, float minDistance, LocationListener listener)` , but what I'm trying to do is a little hack. I want another programm to update gps coords more often than it does. That's why I cant use `LocationManager` (that requires listener parameter), and want to set "global" gps params, that will affect another activity.

EDIT2: I tried with reflections as suggested by Reno.

```
LocationProvider provider = lm.getProvider(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);       
 try {
    Class classGpsProvider = Class.forName("com.android.internal.location.GpsLocationProvider");
        classGpsProvider.cast(provider);
    ...
```

But unfortunately the call to `lm.getProvider()` returns `DummyLocationProvider`, and that one acts like a shadow for `GpsLocationProvider`.

Answer (score 1):

You probably can't do that without [reflection](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/java-reflection/)

You should be using the import `android.location.*`